# How to use ListenableFuture (for ListenableWorker) in MAUI Android?

Tags: android, .net, async-await, maui

There's a [workaround in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401018/calling-a-net-async-method-from-android-worker-in-xamarin) by simply using `.Result` and make it synchronous but I think there should be a proper way to execute asynchronous code in .NET MAUI with [ListenableFuture](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/asynchronous/listenablefuture).

Context: so I am making a Worker that will runs periodically. It may call an `async` method, for example to fetch results from the Internet. Android documentation suggests using [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/threading/listenableworker) and so is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403013/asynchronous-worker-in-android-workmanager). However the "translation" of MAUI/Xamarin is very strange and I cannot really get it to work.

This is Android's code:

```java
public class CallbackWorker extends ListenableWorker {

    public CallbackWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
            Callback callback = new Callback() {
                int successes = 0;

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    completer.setException(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                    successes++;
                    if (successes == 100) {
                        completer.set(Result.success());
                    }
                }
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                downloadAsynchronously("https://www.example.com", callback);
            }
            return callback;
        });
    }
}
```

And this is Xamarin's equivalent but the signature doesn't seem to be identical:

```cs
public class TestTask : ListenableWorker
{
    public TestTask(Context appContext, WorkerParameters workerParams) : base(appContext, workerParams)
    {
    }

    public override IListenableFuture StartWork()
    {
        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.GetFuture(new FutureCallback());
    }

    class FutureCallback : Java.Lang.Object, CallbackToFutureAdapter.IResolver
    {

        public Java.Lang.Object? AttachCompleter(CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer p0)
        {
            // What is Callback here?
            // What do I put in here?
            // I want to do something like this:
            // await DoSomethingAsync();
            // Done
        }

    }

}
```

Please tell me how I can implement the documentation example in .NET MAUI.

EDIT: While trying to explore the API, I realized they do have a convenient extension method `GetAsync` for the other way around (Android `IListenableFuture` -> .NET `Task`) so there must be some easy way to convert the other way I am not aware of? For example:

```cs
var existingWorks = await man.GetWorkInfosByTag(WorkerTag).GetAsync() as IEnumerable<WorkInfo>;
if (existingWorks?.Any() == true) { return; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your class inherit class `ListenableWorker` and implement interface `CallbackToFutureAdapter.IResolver`

Please refer to the following code：

```
public class SimpleListenableWorker : ListenableWorker, CallbackToFutureAdapter.IResolver
    {
        public const string TAG = "SimpleListenableWorker";

        public SimpleListenableWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams) : 
            base(context, workerParams)
        {
        }

        public override IListenableFuture StartWork()
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Started.");
            return CallbackToFutureAdapter.GetFuture(this);
        }

        public Object AttachCompleter(CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer p0)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"Executing.");

            //Switch to background thread.
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //Perform a process here, simulated by a delay for 5 seconds.

                var delaySeconds = 5;
                var progress = 0;
                var progressIncrement = 100 / delaySeconds;
                var dataBuilder = new Data.Builder();

                for (int i = 0; i < delaySeconds+1; i++)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    progress += progressIncrement;
                    dataBuilder.PutInt("Progress", progress);
                    SetProgressAsync(dataBuilder.Build());
                }

                Log.Debug(TAG, "Completed.");

                //Set a Success Result on the completer and return it.
                return p0.Set(Result.InvokeSuccess());
            });

            return TAG;
        }
    }
```

For more information, you can refer article [USING WORKMANAGER AND LISTENABLEWORKER IN XAMARIN ANDROID](https://damien.dennehy.me/using-workmanager-and-listenableworker-in-xamarin-android/).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know Android/Java's Callback is just a Task/Thread in C#. That makes sense now, thanks.